# FreeIPA fails to deploy in kubernetes due to dbus error

Tags: redhat, kubernetes, freeipa, rocky-linux, dbus

I'm facing issues with deploying FreeIPA in kubernetes. I'm using provided image based on rocky 9, but this issue also happens on other images (based on fedora, CentOS etc.). Deploying it my local docker works totally fine, same can't be said about kubernetes. Here's the part of yaml I'm using that describes container:

```
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: IPA_SERVER_HOSTNAME
              value: ipa.example.com
            - name: IPA_SERVER_IP
              value: ""
            - name: IPA_SERVER_INSTALL_OPTS
              value: -U --setup-dns --no-forwarders --no-ntp -r example.com
            - name: PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: admin-password
                  name: freeipa-password
          image: freeipa/freeipa-server:rocky-9
          name: freeipa
          args:
           - "ipa-server-install"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 8Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 300m
              memory: 2Gi
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            privileged: true
```

```
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
```

I didn't include some log parts like exposing ports etc.
Installation goes fine until it tries to start certmonger.service in order to configure pki-tomcatd:

```
2024-03-15   [error] CalledProcessError: CalledProcessError(Command ['/bin/systemctl', 'start', 'certmonger.service'] returned non-zero exit status 1: 'Job for certmonger.service failed because the control process exited with error code.\nSee "systemctl status certmonger.service" and "journalctl -xeu certmonger.service" for details.\n')
2024-03-15 FreeIPA server configuration failed.
```

journalctl -xeu certmonger.service contains following information:

```
Mar 15 09:11:29 freeipa-statefulset-0 certmonger[3652]: 2024-03-15 09:11:29 [3652] Changing to root directory.
Mar 15 09:11:29 freeipa-statefulset-0 certmonger[3652]: 2024-03-15 09:11:29 [3652] Obtaining system lock.
Mar 15 09:11:30 freeipa-statefulset-0 certmonger[3652]: 2024-03-15 09:11:30 [3652] Error connecting to system bus.
Mar 15 09:11:30 freeipa-statefulset-0 certmonger[3652]: Error connecting to D-Bus.
Mar 15 09:11:30 freeipa-statefulset-0 certmonger[3652]: Please verify that the certmonger service is still running.
Mar 15 09:11:30 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: certmonger.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

So apparently dbus is failing to start for some reason,. Here's the output of systemctl status dbus:

```
Mar 15 09:11:29 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[3646]:       main @ ../src/launch/main.c +178Mar 15 09:11:29 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[3646]: Exiting due to fatal error: -107Mar 15 09:11:29 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILUREMar 15 09:11:29 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.Mar 15 09:11:29 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.Mar 15 09:11:29 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.Mar 15 09:11:29 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: Failed to start D-Bus System Message Bus.Mar 15 09:11:30 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.Mar 15 09:11:30 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.Mar 15 09:11:30 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: Failed to start D-Bus System Message Bus.
```

And here's some more info from journalctl on dbus:

```
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[272]: ERROR sockopt_get_peersec @ ../src/util/sockopt.c +41: Invalid argument
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[272]:       broker_new @ ../src/broker/broker.c +105
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[272]:       run @ ../src/broker/main.c +261
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[272]:       main @ ../src/broker/main.c +295
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[271]: ERROR service_add @ ../src/launch/service.c +921: Transport endpoint is not connected
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[271]:       launcher_add_services @ ../src/launch/launcher.c +804
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[271]:       launcher_run @ ../src/launch/launcher.c +1409
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[271]:       run @ ../src/launch/main.c +152
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[271]:       main @ ../src/launch/main.c +178
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 dbus-broker-launch[271]: Exiting due to fatal error: -107
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus-broker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: Failed to start D-Bus System Message Bus.
Mar 15 09:05:41 freeipa-statefulset-0 systemd[1]: dbus.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
```

I've tried to start dbus.service manually, which failed with the same error. I've also noticed that dbus.socket is also failed to start, but it can be successfully started manually.  What can be possible workarounds to make dbus work and why it won't start in first place?